# How to override a dependency gem's view file with one in my gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm working with the Solidus gem that has its own views, and I want to make a gem that overrides some of its views.

Modifying this in a project or custom app is easy since I just have to write the file with the namespace and the name in my project folders, but, what if I want to *gemify* my result? In other words, I want to write this in my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'first_gem'
gem 'my_new_gem'
```

and expect that `app/views/controller/file.html.erb` of `first_gem` to be overriden by the one I have in `my_new_gem`.

I made a `.gem` file with modified views in `app/views` but when I install it via `gem install my_new_gem.gem` and include it with Bundler in a project, views doesn't change anymore.

I've been stuck for hours with this and actually tried this:

- Load gems in order with `Bundler.require`.
- List Solidus gem as a dependency in my gem. My gem is required *after* the dependency as intended, but doesn't work anyway.

Maybe I'm trying something that even isn't working. Maybe I'm not understanding Rubygems at all or maybe I have to preload files with a `lib` script. I'm getting lost where to start or where to find information about this.

I know I can use overrides in Solidus, but I'm changing some layouts and some divs that don't have hooks, so I think this is the only way to go.

Comment: you need to make sure that rails knows where to look for the templates. `prepend_view_path` could be something that works. another approach would be to provide a rake task that copies the files into the project instead of "linking" them through a gem.

Comment: I googled that concept and didn't like it that much because I didn't want to create a controller since I'm just handling views, but checking out other links on the same query I found this:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/26606926/6900659

I think this would work in my case, because on initialization I would be loading the gem contents.

Btw, thinking about it, a rake task or a generator would be a better idea if I want to change the templates in the scope of the new project.

I'm providing an answer for this when I test it out.

Thanks!